# How to remove empty rows in _POST after JQuery Post PHP & Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made a post with ajax Jquery that work fine, but the result is like that:

```
    Array
    (
    [facdatas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [mbr_id] => 26
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [nom] => Gautier Albert
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [adresse] => Avenue du Devin du Village 51
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ville] => 1406 Cronay
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [concerne] => TEST
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [totalFac] => 118.00
            )

    )

[ligneFac] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [designation] => Veste de training CPNS
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [unite] => pièces
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [quantite] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [prixUnite] => 49
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [taxe] => 0.00
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [totLine] => 49.00
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [designation] => Pantalon de training CPNS
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [unite] => pièces
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [quantite] => 1
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [prixUnite] => 69
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [taxe] => 0.00
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [totLine] => 69.00
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [designation] => 
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [unite] => 
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [quantite] => 
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [prixUnite] => 
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [taxe] => 0.00
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [totLine] => 0.00
            )
    ... ... ...
```

Like you can see from the line [12] the rows are empty or with an amount of 0.00, I tried to remove these lines with array_filter($_POST['ligneFac'])
but the result is the same.
There is a way to remove all rows where the first column is empty?

Thank you for help

here is the code to add lines to the form:

```
    $("#insLines").click(function()
{
    $("#matable tbody").append('<tr>'+
                            '<td width="10px">'+
                                '<img id="insArticle" src="../../images/icon_add.png" width="16" height="16">'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td width="250px">'+
                                '<input name="ligneFac[][designation]" type="text" class="facBig" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                           ' <td width="30">'+
                                '<input name="ligneFac[][unite]" type="text" class="facSmall" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                           ' <td width="30">'+
                                '<input name="ligneFac[][quantite]" type="text" class="facSmall" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td width="30">'+
                                '<input name="ligneFac[][prixUnite]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                            '<td width="30">'+
                                '<input name="ligneFac[][taxe]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                           ' <td width="30">'+
                                '<input name="ligneFac[][totLine]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                       '</tr>');

                        iconeClicable();
});
```

Comment: how did you even create this structure? Doesn't seem very code friendly

Comment: Is this print_r from the $_POST? If it is, just don't use the empty fields,. why bother removing them?

Comment: It is right i tried tu do that:
foreach($_POST[ligneFac]) as $lignesFac)
if(!empty($lignesFac['designation']))
 {
  echo $lignesFac['designation']." ";
  echo $lignesFac['unite']." ";
  echo $lignesFac['quantite']. " ";
  echo $lignesFac['prixUnite']." ";
  echo $lignesFac['taxe']." ";
  echo $lignesFac['totLine']. " ";
 }
the result is that echo the first key only...

Comment: **Please, if you have a solution to your own problem, post it as an *answer* instead of editing the question**, otherwise you'll be defeating the Q&A model purpose (future users won't be able to figure out what problem this "question" - which isn't a question anymore - was trying to solve, making it useless).

Answer (score 0):

please try this demo code :-

```
<?php    
    $arr=array();
    $arr['ligneFac'] = array("designation"=>"", "unite"=>"pièces", "quantite"=>"","taxe"=>"0.00");
     foreach($arr['ligneFac'] as $key =>$value)
     {
     if(!empty($value) && $value != "0.00"){
     $arr2['ligneFac'][$key]=$value;
    }
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($arr2);
  echo "</pre>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `print_r()` you posted, I suppose your values are all strings.
In which case, the following should do the trick:

```
$ligneFac = array_filter($_POST['ligneFac'], function($champs) {
    $valeur = reset($champs);
    return ( ('' !== $valeur) && ('0.00' !== $valeur) );
});
```

*(Requires PHP >= 5.3.0 for use of the closure.)*

**UPDATE**

```
foreach ($_POST['ligneFac'] as $i => $champs) {
    list($cle, $valeur) = each($champs);
    if ( ('taxe' !== $cle) && ( ('' === $valeur) || ('0.00' === $valeur) ) ) {
        unset($_POST['ligneFac'][$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is almost what I need, there is juste one value that have '0.00' and have to stay in array, is for taxe.

Comment: With the last code, the Taxe key remain for all rows, it is almost like before.
If i understand your code, on the last line you remove the entire row[$i]. If it is I don't understand the result.

Comment: Yes, for all rows. Should it be removed in some cases? If there are no other fields in the row, for example?

Comment: yes when the first value (designation) is empty and the last value (totLine) is '0.00' the entire line must be removed.
One row is (Designation - Unite - prixUnite - taxe - totLine) only the taxe is at '0.00' and have to stay in array if designation is not empty and totLine > 0

Comment: Do you also intend on flattening the array? Turning it into `Array
(
    [designation] => 
    [totLine] => 69.00
    [taxe] => 0.00
)`

Comment: BTW, I don't see where you have multiple line items? Is `$_POST['ligneFac']` supposed to be an array of arrays (of arrays?)?

Comment: Yes i think this is an error, i'me trying to correct this.
The name of my input are: name="ligneFac[][designation]" because I would have an array FacLine with named key as designation etc...

Comment: The problem is that `name="ligneFac[][designation]"` will give you an array of arrays, each with a single key/ value. If you're already using javascript on your front-end, I suggest you fill in the index, ie. `$('input').attr('name', 'ligneFac[' + i + '][designation]');`

Comment: I'me using javascript and jquerry, but the five first rows of the form are hardcoded and i don't know how to use this java for this lines

Comment: Do the first five rows also have inputs? What are their names? Can you add multiple lines at a time? Do you use jQuery to add lines to the form?

Comment: yes, their names are ligneFac[][designation] etc... No the new lines are created one by one. Yes with jquery code.

Comment: Another detail is that every lines can be filled by a jquery popup with articles or by writting new articles in field input. The goal is to make a bil with adresse bloc, concern and all filled lines.

Comment: What is the jQuery code for adding new lines to the form?

Comment: it is to long to be shown here i will edit my question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,this will remove entries with no value

```
$data = array(array('key1' => 10),array('key2' => 20,),array('key3' => ''));
$result = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, this issue is now resolved.

First, the naming of my form was wrong with this naming:

```
    <input name="ligneFac[][designation]" type="text" class="facBig" />
```

I changed with that :

```
    <input name="ligneFac[1][designation]" type="text" class="facBig" />
```

This give me one array ligneFac line 1 with designation as value etc...

Next i had to change the code to add some new lines with thi code:

```
var nbr_tr = $('#fac_table tr').length;
var nbr_rows = nbr_tr -1; //to remove the header from calc.
newNum = nbr_rows + 1;

$("#matable tbody").append('<tr>'+
                        '<td width="10px">'+
                            '<img id="insArticle" src="../../images/icon_add.png" width="16" height="16">'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td width="250px">'+
                            '<input name="ligneFac['+newNum+'][designation]" type="text" class="facBig" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                       ' <td width="30">'+
                            '<input name="ligneFac['+newNum+'][unite]" type="text" class="facSmall" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                       ' <td width="30">'+
                            '<input name="ligneFac['+newNum+'][quantite]" type="text" class="facSmall" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td width="30">'+
                            '<input name="ligneFac['+newNum+'][prixUnite]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td width="30">'+
                            '<input name="ligneFac['+newNum+'][taxe]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                       ' <td width="30">'+
                            '<input name="ligneFac['+newNum+'][totLine]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                   '</tr>');

iconeClicable();
});
```

and now the resulting array is code friendly...

```
    Array
(
[mbrDatas] => Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [mbr_id] => 26
            [nom] => Gautier Albert
            [adresse] => Avenue du Devin du Village 51
            [ville] => 1406 Cronay
        )

)

[facdatas] => Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [concerne] => TEST
            [totalFac] => 147.00
        )

)

[ligneFac] => Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [designation] => Veste
            [unite] => pièces
            [quantite] => 1
            [prixUnite] => 98
            [taxe] => 0.00
            [totLine] => 98.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [designation] => Veste de training
            [unite] => pièces
            [quantite] => 1
            [prixUnite] => 49
            [taxe] => 0.00
            [totLine] => 49.00
        )

)

)
```

and without empty lines using the updated code of "Francis Eytan Dortort".

```
    foreach ($_POST['ligneFac'] as $i => $champs)
    {
    list($cle, $valeur) = each($champs);
    if ( ('taxe' !== $cle) && ( ('' === $valeur) || ('0.00' === $valeur)         ) )
    {
    unset($_POST['ligneFac'][$i]);
    }
    }
```

Hope to this is helpful for anyone...